# Given a list of items each associated with a color, how can I depict such a coloring?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, networkx

So I'm working with a function in NetworkX that partitions a graph's vertices into blocks which receive colors (in (0, 1) ) which are then used to color the nodes of the graph(which correspond to blocks of the partition). I would like to be able to depict, given an ordering of the nodes, in which class each node belongs.

In particular, assume we have n nodes labels 1, 2, ... n. What I would like to do is have a scalable method for plotting one rectangular shape oriented horizontally that is split into slivers, with each sliver completely filled in with which ever color corresponds to that node's class in the partition. So the first sliver will be colored red if node 1 belongs to the class which has received the red color, the second sliver will be colored green if its class is green, and so on.

I'm not sure what such a graph is called so I'm having trouble searching for it. Perhaps y'all can help.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part NetworkX uses matplotlib to plot graphs.
Check out the gallery for examples:
http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/gallery.html

This may be a duplicate question:
[How to determine specific color and size of chosen nodes in Networkx graph plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036843/how-to-determine-specific-color-and-size-of-chosen-nodes-in-networkx-graph-plot)

This one is close to what you are looking for without the dual color info.
http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html

I'm not really sure what you intended by saying "and so on" so here is the 3d version with how to deal with color specifically. 
http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/mplot3d/scatter3d_demo.html

Comment: The question you linked in the second link is not what I was looking for, but thanks for the link to the gallery. I found what I was looking for: http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/api/colorbar_only.html